# How to sum the values of multiple rows, group by id and keep the rows of all unique ids with pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

I have a file with the following columns: 'id','H1','H2','H3','H4','H5','H6','H7','H8','H9','H10','H11','H12','H13','H14','H15','H16','H17','H18','H19','H20','H21','H22','H23','H24'

see an example:
[image]

I want to sum the values of columns but grouping by id and keep only the rows of the unique id (i.e., 1,2,3,4,5,6)
I tried the following but the sum does not work.

```
 col_names=['id','H1','H2','H3','H4','H5','H6','H7','H8','H9','H10','H11','H12','H13','H14','H15','H16','H17','H18','H19','H20','H21','H22','H23','H24']
    df = pd.read_csv(i,sep='\t',names=col_names)
    
    cols = df.filter(regex='^H').columns
    
    df.groupby(['id'])[cols].sum()
    
    df_final = df.sort_index(by=['id'], ascending=[True])
    df_final.to_csv(outfile,sep='\t',index=False,header=False)
```

Edited/Update:

I am trying the following, since I have multiple files with thousands of rows (in case the file has 150000 rows):

```
col_names=['id','H1','H2','H3','H4','H5','H6','H7','H8','H9','H10','H11','H12','H13','H14','H15','H16','H17','H18','H19','H20','H21','H22','H23','H24']
    df = pd.read_csv(i,sep='\t',names=col_names)
    
    cols = df.filter(regex='^H').columns

    grouped=df.groupby(['id'])[cols].sum()
    unique_ids = [range(1,150000)]
    grouped = grouped.loc[unique_ids]
```

I get the error

```
key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: u"None of [Index([(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, ...)], dtype='object', name=u'id')] are in the [index]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to assign the result of the groupby operation to a new variable in order to keep the aggregated data.
Also, it's better using the sort_values method instead of the deprecated sort_index method to sort. you can do it in this way

```
import pandas as pd

col_names=['id','H1','H2','H3','H4','H5','H6','H7','H8','H9','H10','H11','H12','H13','H14','H15','H16','H17','H18','H19','H20','H21','H22','H23','H24']

df = pd.read_csv(i,sep='\t',names=col_names)
cols = df.filter(regex='^H').columns

grouped = df.groupby(['id'])[cols].sum()

unique_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
grouped = grouped.loc[unique_ids]

grouped = grouped.sort_values(by='id')
grouped.to_csv(outfile,sep='\t',index=False,header=False)
```

Comment: thank you, but the file was just an example, in fact I have thousands of rows (ids). In addition, I want to make the code general since the number of Unique_ids may differ in different files. Is this possible?

Comment: how I could define the unique_ids as a range of e.g. 1 to max_rows?

Comment: I have edited my question please check the error I get

Answer (score 0):

Use list symbols only when necessary;
`[]` is redundant for the `range`, the `[]` behind `loc` will generate a list, just use

```
unique_ids = range(1,150000)
grouped = grouped.loc[unique_ids]
```

Check on https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range

Comment: now the error is : KeyError: u"None of [Int64Index([     1,      2,      3,      4,      5,      6,      7,      8,\n                 9,     10,\n            ...\n            153415, 153416, 153417, 153418, 153419, 153420, 153421, 153422,\n            153423, 153424],\n           dtype='int64', name=u'id', length=153424)] are in the [index]"

Comment: the unique_ids values is in fact the "ID" column for which I want to group and sum the values H1-H24

Comment: I resolved similar error messages in my test data. What passed to `loc` should be a subset of 'ID' values with a list-like style.  You can try to adjust `unique_ids` to fit your data.

Comment: How I could do that?Could you please be more specific? The column ID has values ranging from 1 to 153424 and this is the range I define in unique_ids. Is this any other way to just sum up the values of each H1,H2 etc. grouping by id?